# How to escape ":" in Logic Apps Search Query?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to get only new emails not reply or forwarded emails.
Here is my query:

**(subject:return NOT "re:" OR subject:shipment NOT "re:") AND (attachment: return NOT exception OR attachment:shipment NOT exception) AND (subject:return NOT adjustment) AND (subject:return NOT "fw:" OR subject:shipment NOT "fw:")**

[image]

But I get these error instead. These query runs fine in MS Outlook application.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Syntax error: character ':' is not valid at position 24 in '\"(subject:return NOT \"re:\" OR subject:shipment NOT \"re:\") AND (attachment: return NOT exception OR attachment:shipment NOT exception) AND (subject:return NOT adjustment) AND (subject:return NOT \"fw:\" OR subject:shipment NOT \"fw:\")\"'.\r\nclientRequestId: c6f3d1e1-b137-4c5d-acfd-1434ff85a610\r\nserviceRequestId: 2925969d-f4df-4a84-90b1-b9977f08a024",
  "error": {
    "message": "Syntax error: character ':' is not valid at position 24 in '\"(subject:return NOT \"re:\" OR subject:shipment NOT \"re:\") AND (attachment: return NOT exception OR attachment:shipment NOT exception) AND (subject:return NOT adjustment) AND (subject:return NOT \"fw:\" OR subject:shipment NOT \"fw:\")\"'."
  },
  "source": "office365-wus2.azconn-wus2.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "/" escape character as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shashi/2018/01/29/when-you-have-escape-characters-in-the-string-the-liquid-template-fails/)

```
 | Escape | Replace: ‘&quot;’, ‘\”‘ |
```